# How to get typeof key in array of objects?

Tags: typescript

Given

```
type PageInfo = {
    title: string
    key: string
}

const PAGES: PageInfo[] = [
    {
        key: 'trip_itinerary',
        title: "Trip Itinerary",
    },
    {
        key: 'trip_details',
        title: "Trip Details",
    },
    {
        key: 'passenger_info',
        title: "Passenger Information",
    },
]
```

Can I pull out a type for the `key` key like `'trip_itinerary'|'trip_details'|'passenger_info'` ? I want to use it as the key for a `Record`, but I'd rather not write it manually.

Something like

```
type PageKey = typeof PAGES[???].key
```

I can swap `PAGES` w/ `satifies` if it helps...

```
const PAGES = [
    ...
] satisfies PageInfo[]
```

Comment: You can't do it if you annotate `PAGES` since the compiler would throw away the info you need.  You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlLolN) instead; does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Wow lots of edits happening; let me know when it stabilizes)

Comment: No, all TypeScript type info disappears at runtime.  `typeof` will only return for example "string" or "object", not one of your TypeScript types.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, that's exactly what I wanted. I thought `satisfies` might help here but I wouldn't have thought of `as const satisfies readonly PageInfo[]` and I didn't know you could do `[number]`. That's perfect!

Comment: Okay I'll write up an answer when I get the chance

Comment: I think your best bet is to log those values like "trip_itinerary" at runtime, and then write some simple code that can assemble the TypeScript type definition for you by concatenating them together with "|".

Comment: @user2740650 This isn't a runtime thing. I don't want a string with pipes in it. I want a TypeScript *type*.

Comment: @mpen I meant form 'trip_itinerary'|'trip_details'|'passenger_info' at runtime by reading the values and assembling them just like that.

Comment: @user2740650 I don't know what you're trying to say.  `'trip_itinerary'|'trip_details'|'passenger_info'` is a **type** (union of consts) not a *string*. Also you needn't bother, jcalz already solved it.

Comment: I meant you could produce that type definition at runtime with a trivial program, and then copy paste that generated type definition into your TypeScript code, but if the code jcalz suggested works for you, that's great!

Comment: @user2740650 Oh.. OK, I see what you're saying. That's an interesting suggestion, but I'd just do some multi-cursor shennanigans in my IDE if I wanted to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `PAGES` as `PageInfo[]` then the compiler will dutifully widen `PAGES` to that type, allowing you to `push()` arbitrary `PageInfo` instances onto it, or rearrange its contents, or change the `key` and properties on any of its elements.  The compiler intentionally forgets about the specific order or contents of `PAGES` and their particular properties, since these are subject to change.  But that's not what you want.

Instead you want the compiler to *infer* the type of `PAGES`.  And if you want the inferred type to reflect [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `key` properties from the initializer, you will probably want to use [a `const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to give the compiler a hint that you care about such specifics:

```
const PAGES = [
    {
        key: 'trip_itinerary',
        title: "Trip Itinerary",
    },
    {
        key: 'trip_details',
        title: "Trip Details",
    },
    {
        key: 'passenger_info',
        title: "Passenger Information",
    },
] as const;
```

Now `PAGES` has the type

```
/* const PAGES: readonly [{
    readonly key: "trip_itinerary";
    readonly title: "Trip Itinerary";
}, {
    readonly key: "trip_details";
    readonly title: "Trip Details";
}, {
    readonly key: "passenger_info";
    readonly title: "Passenger Information";
}] */
```

and you can compute `PageKey` as follows:

```
type PageKey = typeof PAGES[number]["key"];
// type PageKey = "trip_itinerary" | "trip_details" | "passenger_info"
```

---

This works as desired, and you could stop there if you want.

Still, the compiler won't care whether `PAGES` is an array of `PageInfo` elements or not.  If you want the compiler to verify that type this without *widening* to it, you can use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator):

```
const PAGES = [
    {
        key: 'trip_itinerary',
        title: "Trip Itinerary",
    },
    {
        key: 'trip_details',
        title: "Trip Details",
    },
    {
        key: 'passenger_info',
        title: "Passenger Information",
    },
] as const satisfies readonly PageInfo[];
```

Note that we had to write `satisfies readonly PageInfo[]` instead of `satisfies PageInfo[]`.  That's because [the `readonly X[]` array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) is *wider* than [the read-write `X[]` array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type).  Since `as const` produces `readonly` arrays, then it isn't necessarily the case that `PAGES satisfies PageInfo[]`.

Anyway now the compiler will complain if you fail to initialize `PAGES` with valid `PageInfo` elements:

```
const PAGES_OOPS = [
    {
        key: 'trip_itinerary',
        title: "Trip Itinerary",
    },
    {
        key: 'trip_details',
        title: 123, // oops
    },
    {
        key: 'passenger_info',
        title: "Passenger Information",
    },
] as const satisfies readonly PageInfo[] // error!
// Type '{ readonly key: "trip_details"; readonly title: 123; }' 
// is not assignable to type 'PageInfo'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#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-I6y2Oz28iYRxOZwuKoeUeeWFeUFDKB7FYTBWAAQg+MM-AjMx8EuakcTpKdMxZdF4PZVUTygZcVzQsRTCgSCoGOKBUEwA5OiYSgEFQOAvToChsHtMwf0vQYADogA)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering why the `readonly` was necessary. Good explanation!